# What is the area in front of a car where brand logo is held called?

Tags: car, design

I have seen the design of so many cars out there specially there front panel where logo is rested, it really looks eye catching. What do we call that panel in automotive terms ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general area could be called the "nose" of the vehicle.

Depending on the vehicle's design, the logo may be found on the bonnet/front hood, front grille or front fender.

> [image: BMW i8]
>   **Bonnet, BMW i8**

---

> [image: Mercedes G Wagon]
>   **Grille, Mercedes G Wagon**

---

> [image: Maserati Ghibli]
>   **Front Fender & Grille, Maserati Ghibli**

Comment: @Arjuna - Zaid just delivers quality, it's how he rolls.   :)